# Comparing differences in an entrie workspace in TFS

Tags: tfs, compare

As TFS maintains an idea of the version that is downloaded on the client, such that "Get Latest" might not get the latest version; I was wondering if there was an easy way to report differences across an entire workspace?

I only ask as a member of my team is leaving immanently, and our IT department need to recycle his laptop very quickly, and I'm a little concerned that there is potential for some changes not to have been changed in.

Comment: On what scope do you need to do this and what version of TFS are you using? TFS 2010 has a "Pending Changes" window that shows you everything you have that differs with TFS, but it's only for your single solution and not all solutions.

Comment: @Jaxidian We're still on TFS-2008 (until the official release on the 12th) which does have a pending changes on a per-workspace version, but it only shows stuff that has been checked out properly - I'm concerned more about changes that have been made without being checked out properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry misread the question.

**If you have proper checkouts you can just do the following:**

Go to the command line, and at the top if the workspace type

```
tf checkin . /recursive
```

This will present the what's outstanding in the workspace.

Or just shelve the lot to the serve and then you can peruse at leisure.

```
tf shelve
```

**Oherwise the other thing I would do is**

Just get the latest version of the software to another Directory and then use the excellent [beyond compare tool from scootersoft](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) to compare the directories recursively.

Once you have the files just copy the list to a bat file calling tf checkout on each one.

Then do tf shelve.

Comment: That's probably better than my "force a get latest of the current version and see what it moans about" option, nad something I should've thought of sooner, being a fan of Beyond Compare...

Comment: lol - honestly have more faith the tool - its awesome (hahaahha)